# Excel 1004 error vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

i have this line:

```
LArticol.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Serie.Value,[TEST], 2, 0)
```

And my error is Run-time error 1004
I've try with

```
LArticol.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Serie.Value,ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("TEST"), 2, 0)
```

but...same thing
i really need help

CODE:

```
Private Sub Serie_Change() 
    LArticol.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Serie.Value,ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("TEST"), 2, 0) End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
Call Serii 
End Sub
```

**Serii module**

```
Sub Serii() 
Dim Ssheet As Worksheet 
Set Ssheet =
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE") 
If Ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
    sslr = 3 Else
    sslr = Ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
End If 
For X = 3 To sslr
    UserForm1.Serie.AddItem Ssheet.Cells(X, 1) 
Next X 
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the value in `Serie` is located in the first column of `Test`?  If it is not in there it will through an error.

Comment: How is `Serie` declared? Is that a single cell?

Comment: Believe your code looks good. Can you post how you've declared Serie as nbayly asked?

Comment: Please do not put code in the comments.  Please edit your original post instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It looks like `Serie` is a control object on the UserForm. This code will definitely 1004 if the value is not found in the range specified by the VLOOKUP function.

Comment: Serie is combobox

Comment: @DavidZemens the value from "Serie.Value" show me what value i've in the cell but...it's something wrong at range...i don't know..

Comment: If you do `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("TEST").Address`, what output do you get?

Comment: @DavidZemens if i'll put this above _"LArticol.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Serie.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("Test"), 2, 0)"_ ?

Comment: Yes, you put it above that line and step through code using F8 key. Or you can do `?ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("TEST").Address` in the Immediate pane in the VBE.

Comment: same thing...error 1004

Comment: That will suggest that no such range named "Test" exists in the worksheet.

Comment: but is it...... this is in name manager: name-TEST
Refers to:
=ELECTRICE!$A$3:$H$1048576

Comment: Does simple `Debug.Print Range("Test").Address` produce the same 1004?

Comment: And just to be certain, the error raises on the `Debug` statement? Also, please include the *full text* from Error Description.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ELECTRICE` the active sheet? `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` operates on the active sheet unless you tell it otherwise.

Also,

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("TEST")
```

will return `$A$3:$H$1048576`. If you want it to return `ELECTRICE!$A$3:$H$1048576` then you should use

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("TEST").RefersTo
```

Keep in mind too that this requires the named range's scope to be defined as `Workbook` and not a specific sheet.

[image]

Comment: _Run-Time ERROR '1004'_
_Unable to get the vlookup propery of the worksheetfunction class_

I've try "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ELECTRICE").Range("TEST").Address" too, the "ELECTRICE" is sheet1...all is right...but i don't know how to get the value from another chell in other type...all i get is error 1004...